# Can StackExchange.Redis connection be suspended if not used for a long time?

Tags: stackexchange.redis

Our application runs many services, all connecting to Redis using StackExchange.Redis. This causes a connection overload on the Redis server.

However, most of the services will actually use Redis one hour during the day.

We were wondering - is there any configuration we can set in StackExchange.Redis, which will automatically disconnect the connection if not used for a long time, and will reconnect when next accessed?